# Genitive plurals

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the following?

```
room's window
room's windows
rooms' window
rooms' windows
```

I'm mainly interested in the last two constructs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> room's window

A window belonging to a room.

> room's windows

Multiple windows belonging to a room.

> rooms' window

A window belonging to multiple rooms (probably a window connecting two rooms)

> rooms' windows

Multiple windows belonging to multiple rooms

The plurality of *windows* distinguishes how many different windows there are.
The location of the apostrophe in *rooms* distinguishes how many different rooms there are.
`'s` signifies that there is only one room and that `room` is in the genitive case.
`s'` should be thought of as `rooms`, with the apostrophe indicating it is in the genetive.

Comment: My confusion was if `rooms' window` means one window per room or one window for all rooms.

Comment: @Alexandru Typically, one window for all rooms.

Comment: I am curious, in the spoken form, would you pronounce the second 's on the last two? i.e. rooms-es

Comment: @Anthony K: **room's** and **rooms'** are pronounced the same, AFAICT. you'd have to figure it out from context

Comment: @Claudiu: That's correct. The only time you'd say "roomses" is if you meet a man named "Mr. Rooms" and you want to refer to his whole family, "The Roomses". Or if you're Sméagol from The Lord of the Rings.